# JavaScriptSerializer Deserialize with DateTime or DateTimeOffset

Tags: .net, json, datetime, deserialization, datetimeoffset

VB2012 compiled against .NET4.5: This has been boggling my head for the last couple days. I have json data that I am parsing with the JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize class. One of the fields is presented as follows:

```
depart 2017-09-22T00:45:00-07:00
```

Which is the local time of the departure (this is in Los Angeles).

In my wrapper class I have written

```
Public Class JsonLeg
    Public depart As DateTime
    Public blah...many more fields
End Class
```

I ingest the json data and use JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize to parse it. After this I debug the output and it looks like this

```
depart                 [Kind=Local] 2017-09-22T02:45:00
depart.ToLocalTime     [Kind=Local] 2017-09-22T02:45:00
depart.ToUniversalTime [Kind=Utc  ] 2017-09-22T07:45:00
```

That looks all well but the ToLocalTime just converts it to my computer's time zone which is in Dallas. What I need is the **local time in LA 2017-09-22T00:45:00** to compare against a list of dates that do not have a Kind. How would I pull out the original location's local time rather than my computer's local time?

I did test using DateTimeOffset as the variable but am afraid I don't understand what the deserializer is doing when it parses the json data.

The debug for that looks like:

```
depart.DateTime      [Kind=Unspecified] 2017-09-22T00:45:00
depart.LocalDateTime [Kind=Local      ] 2017-09-22T02:45:00
depart.UtcDateTime   [Kind=Utc        ] 2017-09-22T07:45:00
```

In this case the DateTimeOffset.DateTime gives me what I need. But why? I am trying to understand what the differences are and how each one gets parsed by the deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) extended format, with offset.  This is also covered by [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

When you deserialize a string in this format into a `DateTime` using the `JavaScriptSerializer`, it is making a rather grand assumption that it was generated from another `DateTime` with `Kind=Local`.  Since the offsets may or may not match between your machine and the one that generated the data, it first applies the supplied offset to get to UTC, then it converts back to your local time zone.  This is probably not the behavior you want, and there isn't a very good way to get `JavaScriptSerializer` to behave differently.  Parsing into a `DateTimeOffset` makes much more sense.  The resulting date, time, and offset portions then match exactly what were supplied.

Once you have a `DateTimeOffset`, calling `.DateTime` that gives you back just the date and time portion, with the resulting kind to `Unspecified`.  This is the standard behavior for all `DateTimeOffset` instances, not just those that come through parsing.  The reason is that the offset could be anything, and mapping it to either `Local` or `Utc` would be in error.

Likewise, the `.LocalDateTime` converts to local time taking the offset into account (similarly to as if you parsed directly to a `DateTime`).  The `.UtcDateTime` takes the offset into account and converts to UTC, similarly to if you called `.ToUniversalTime()` on the `DateTime` version.

Also, you should consider using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead of `JavaScriptSerializer`.  The majority of the .NET community, including Microsoft, now uses this library for JSON serialization. It is much more flexible, and tends to do the right thing out-of-the-box when it comes to dates and times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.It makes sense to me now. I wanted a light way to convert the data and though if MS already had a parser then I would use that.I think I will consider moving to json.net if my parsing becomes more complex. Thanks a bunch.